# Is "avoid the yo-yo problem" a valid reason to allow the "primitive obsession"?

Tags: object-oriented, coding-style

According to *[When is primitive obsession not a code smell?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365017/when-is-primitive-obsession-not-a-code-smell)*, I should create a ZipCode object to represent a zip code instead of a String object.

However, in my experience, I prefer to see

```
public class Address{
    public String zipCode;
}
```

instead of

```
public class Address{
    public ZipCode zipCode;
}
```

because I think the latter one requires me to move to the ZipCode class to understand the program.

And I believe I need to move between many classes to see the definition if every primitive data fields were replaced by a class, which feels as if suffering from the [yo-yo problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem) (an anti-pattern).

So I would like to move the ZipCode methods into a new class, for example:

Old:

```
public class ZipCode{
    public boolean validate(String zipCode){
    }
}
```

New:

```
public class ZipCodeHelper{
    public static boolean validate(String zipCode){
    }
}
```

so that only the one who needs to validate the zip code would depend on the ZipCodeHelper class. And I found another "benefit" of keeping the primitive obsession: it keeps the class looks like its serialized form, if any, for example: an address table with string column zipCode.

My question is, is "avoiding the yo-yo problem" (move between class definitions) a valid reason to allow the "primitive obsession"?

Comment: "I should create a ZipCode object to represent zip code instead of a String object." ...Why? Zip codes would have no additional functionality to attach, and the most common thing you'll do with them is render them as part of a full address. *Maybe* you'll pass them to a geocoding service, but a custom object makes that harder. The Address class itself can validate (which shouldn't be more than just correct length and optional parts to avoid restricting valid inputs unknown to you at delivery time). I just don't see any practical advantage to having a zip code object; it's just boilerplate.

Comment: @jpmc26 Then you would be shocked to see how complex our zip code object is -- not saying it's right, but it does exist

Comment: @JaredGoguen On the contrary, badly designed code is not at all shocking. lol. I'm sure there exist cases where my assertions are wrong, but the point is that you should be asking the question of what *practical* advantage there actually is. Don't just blindly try to apply theory. Every structure you create in code should very obviously *solve a practical problem* that you have. Most apps that use zip codes don't do enough with them for a dedicated type to solve any problem.

Comment: @jpmc26, I fail to see how you get from "complex" to "badly-designed."  Complex code is often the result of simple code coming into contact with the complexity of the real world rather than the ideal world we might wish existed.  ["Back to that two page function. Yes, I know, it’s just a simple function to display a window, but it has grown little hairs and stuff on it and nobody knows why. Well, I’ll tell you why: those are bug fixes."](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/)

Comment: @jpmc26 - the point of wrapping objects like ZipCode is type safety. Zip code is not a string, it's a zip code. If a function expects a zip code, you should only be able to pass a zip code, not a string.

Comment: This feels highly language specific, different languages do different things here. @DavorŽdralo In the same stretch we should also add a lot of numeric types. "only positive integers", "only even numbers" could all also be types.

Comment: @Kyralessa Nice straw man. I don't. I go from "doesn't solve any problems" to "badly designed." That is unnecessary complexity. Type safety on zip codes is just unnecessary. It's not going to solve any problems. What do you seriously think is going to happen? Someone is going to pass a zip code where a first name is needed? Only someone incompetent enough to fire is going to not notice a screw up that big when they write it.

Comment: @paul23 Yes indeed, and the main reason we *don't* have those is that a lot of languages don't support elegant ways to define them. It's perfectly reasonable to define "age" as a different type from "temperature in degrees celsius", if only so that "userAge == currentTemperature" is detected as nonsense.

Comment: @jpmc26 I get that you're saying, in the general case, "don't write code that doesn't solve any problem"; but you did then imply that code you've never seen was "badly designed", just because *you* don't know what problem it solves, so it seems a bit rich to accuse someone else of attacking a straw man.

Comment: @IMSoP If you read the "lol." and the sentence immediately following the one you're referring to, you'll see that I was very clearly not serious.

Comment: @paul23 - that's exactly what you should do if performance allows it.

Comment: @jpmc26 I think that didn't come across as clearly as you hoped, and that's why Kyralessa thought you were jumping from "complex" (as described by Jared Goguen) to "badly designed" (as used by you in the comment you intended not to be taken seriously).

Comment: It doesn’t appear that anyone has pointed out that you haven’t understood the Wikipedia article you linked to. The yo-yo problem describes deep chains of inheritance, not the use of domain modeling via a type system. In fact, *composition* is one of the recommended methods for avoiding the yo-yo problem. I would recommend you read that article a bit more closely.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The assumption is that you *don't* need to yo-yo to the ZipCode class to understand the Address class. If ZipCode is well-designed it should be obvious what it does just by reading the Address class.

Programs are not read end-to-end - typically programs are far too complex to make this possible. You cannot keep all the code in a program in your mind at the same time. So we use abstractions and encapsulations to "chunk" the program into meaningful units, so you can look at one part of the program (say the Address class) without having to read all code it depends on.

For example I'm sure you don't yo-yo into reading the source code for String every time you encounter String in code.

Renaming the class from ZipCode to ZipCodeHelper suggest there now is two separate concepts: a zip code and a zip code helper. So twice as complex. And now the type system cannot help you distinguish between an arbitrary string and a valid zip code since they have the same type. This is where "obsession" is appropriate: You are suggesting a more complex and less safe alternative just because you want to avoid a simple wrapper type around a primitive.

Using a primitive is IMHO justified in the cases where there is no validation or other logic depending on this particular type. But as soon as you add any logic, it is much simpler if this logic is encapsulated with the type.

As for serialization I think it sounds like a limitation in the framework you are using. Surely you should be able to serialize a ZipCode to a string or map it to a column in a database.

Comment: I agree with the "meaningful units" (main-) part, but not so much that a zip code and zip code validation are the same concept. `ZipCodeHelper` (which I would rather call `ZipCodeValidator`) might very well establish a connection to a web service to do it's job. That would not be part of the _single responsibility_ "hold the zip code data". Making the type system disallow invalid zip codes can still be achieved by making the `ZipCode` constructor the equivalent of Java's package-private and calling that with a `ZipCodeFactory` which always calls the validator.

Comment: @R.Schmitz: That is not what "responsibility" means in the sense of the single responsibility principle. But in any case, you should of course use as many classes as you need as long as you encapsulate the zip code and its validation. The OP suggest a helper *instead of* encapsulating the zip code, which is a bad idea.

Comment: I want to respectfully disagree. SRP means a class should have "one, and only one, reason to be changed" (change in "what a zipcode consists of" vs. "how it is validated"). This specific case here is further elaborated on in the book _Clean Code_: "_Objects hide their data behind abstractions and expose functions that operate on that data. Data structure expose their data and have no meaningful functions._" -  `ZipCode` would be a "data structure" and `ZipCodeHelper` an "object' . In any case, I think we agree that we shouldn't have to pass web connections to the ZipCode constructor.

Comment: *Using a primitive is IMHO justified in the cases where there is no validation or other logic depending on this particular type.* => I disagree. Even if all values are valid, I would still favor conveying the semantics to the language rather than use primitives. If a function can be called on a primitive type which is nonsensical for its current semantic usage, then it should not be a primitive type, it should be a proper type with only the sensible functions defined. (As an example, using `int` as ID allows multiplying an ID by an ID...)

Comment: @R.Schmitz I think ZIP codes are a poor example for the distinction you're making. Something that changes often might be a candidate for separate `Foo` and `FooValidator` classes. We *could* have a `ZipCode` class that validates the format and a `ZipCodeValidator` that hits some Web service to check that a correctly formatted `ZipCode` is actually current. We know that ZIP codes change. But practically, we're going to have a list of valid ZIP codes encapsulated in `ZipCode`, or in some local database.

Comment: @TKK I'd say that's only the "standard" for smaller apps. As soon as you write e.g. a webshop that's not locally restricted, it's probably easier to use a service, like e.g. [zipcodeapi](https://www.zipcodeapi.com/) instead of encoding [all of this](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/) into a hundreds LOC ZipCode class.

Comment: @TKK Having a zip code database built into your app is a good way to unnecessarily create a maintenance burden. The gains of actually trying to validate zip codes by number are just not worth it in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: @jpmc26 I would have agreed before shipping APIs started getting "smart" and trying to "fix" things instead of returning errors. My company has shipped packages to non-existent addresses because national carriers' shipping APIs "fixed" real addresses that would have been recognizable to a human. I'm generally against pre-validating data that's being passed to an API, but addresses need a few sanity checks these days.

Comment: @TKK Your design problem is that you're using a service that automatically modifies your data. That's a huge no-go. These address changes need to be presented *to the user* and **approved** before being applied. See if the carriers provide a pre-flight API that you can use to see what they'll do to the address when the user submits their order.

Comment: @jpmc26 Unfortunately there's no choice. (USPS is the main culprit, though not the only one.) Web orders are a different team upstream from me. I can only kludge in some sanity checks when the address goes from our ERP to the shipper API, days, weeks, or months after the order was placed.

Comment: @TKK So then you also have a dysfunctional team because you can't escalate problems and get fixes in the right place. Sure. Existing bad design and bad organizational dynamics sometimes force your hand. But that doesn't mean the design choices are good. It just means you're making do with a bad design that's beyond your control. That's an  important distinction to make. Although I'd at least try to arrange a discussion with the other team and make them aware of the problem you're facing and ask if they could do anything.

Comment: @jpmc26 The right place for a fix is in the shipper API. Who ever thought it was a good idea to silently change data instead of returning an error?

Comment: @TKK Yes, agreed. Again, you're making do with a bad design decision. But thinking about your end a bit more, what happens currently when a zip code validation fails? "The user" could be any actual person who intervenes in the system. Why couldn't that same process be triggered by an address that a carrier "corrects"? USPS provides some [documentation](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/documentation-updates.htm) on their APIs. It looks like they do have some kind of address validation service. You could potentially validate there and then flag it the same way you're currently doing.

Comment: @jpmc26 USPS is a couple layers deep behind some other third-party services that we use. The problem is when USPS changes e.g. "123 W 45th St" to "45 E 45th St" because it doesn't recognize the former. We'd practically need an AI to distinguish those really wrong changes from harmless ones like "100 W Elm" to "100 W Elm St". And again, USPS is not the only culprit. But it happens so rarely that the most cost-effective solution is to perform some really basic pre-validation on our end. (Which our expensive ERP ought to do when the order goes in, but *everything sucks*...)

Answer (score 56):

If can do:

```java
new ZipCode("totally invalid zip code");
```

And the constructor for ZipCode does:

```java
ZipCodeHelper.validate("totally invalid zip code");
```

Then you've broken encapsulation, and added a pretty silly dependency to the ZipCode class. If the constructor *doesn't* call `ZipCodeHelper.validate(...)` then you have isolated logic in its own island without actually enforcing it. You can create invalid zip codes.

The `validate` method should be a static method on the ZipCode class. Now the knowledge of a "valid" zip code is bundled together with the ZipCode class. Given that your code examples look like Java, the constructor of ZipCode should throw an exception if an incorrect format is given:

```java
public class ZipCode {
    private String zipCode;

    public ZipCode(string zipCode) {
        if (!validate(zipCode))
            throw new IllegalFormatException("Invalid zip code");

        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public static bool validate(String zipCode) {
        // logic to check format
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return zipCode;
    }
}
```

The constructor checks the format and throws an exception, thereby preventing invalid zip codes from being created, and the static `validate` method is available to other code so the logic of checking the format is encapsulated in the ZipCode class.

There is no "yo-yo" in this variant of the ZipCode class. It's just called proper Object Oriented Programming.

---

We are also going to ignore internationalization here, which may necessitate another class called ZipCodeFormat or PostalService (e.g. PostalService.isValidPostalCode(...), PostalService.parsePostalCode(...), etc.).

Comment: Note: The main advantage with @Greg Burkhardt's approach here is that if someone gives you a ZipCode object, you can trust that it contains a valid string without having to check it again, since its type and the fact that it was successfully constructed gives you that guarantee. If you instead passed strings around, you might feel a need to "assert validate(zipCode)" at various places in your code just to be sure that you had a valid zip code, but with a successfully constructed ZipCode object, you can trust that its contents are valid without having to check them again.

Comment: @SomeGuy While the disadvantage is that you're having a ["vexing" exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) here. Either you surround every ZipCode creation with a try-catch, or you always check it twice. However, as long as your validation code is minor, this should pose no issue for [internal, embedded, game and throwaway apps](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/05/06/five-worlds/).

Comment: @R.Schmitz: The `ZipCode.validate` method is the pre-check that can be performed before invoking a constructor that throws an exception.

Comment: @R.Schmitz: If you are concerned about a vexing exception, an alternate approach to construction is to make the ZipCode constructor private, and provide a public static factory function (Zipcode.create?) that performs validation of the passed-in parameters, returns null if unsuccessful, and otherwise constructs a ZipCode object and returns it. The caller will always have to check for a null return value, of course. On the other hand, if you are in the habit, for instance, of always validating (regex? validate? etc.) before constructing a ZipCode, the exception may not be so vexing in practice.

Comment: A factory function that returns an Optional<ZipCode> is also a possibility. Then the caller has no choice but to explicitly handle possible failure of the factory function.  Regardless, in either case, the error will be discovered somewhere near where it was created rather than possibly much later, by client code far from the original problem.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yes, that's what I mean with "always check it twice": Once to see if it's valid to construct, and once when actually constructing.

Comment: @SomeGuy Yeah sure, the factory is a possibility to avoid this, but that's a different solution than the one given here, which is the point: Other solutions have other advantages. Checking for null is not really a disadvantage compared to this answer, because here you will also always have to check (if it's valid before constructing it, which checks it again) - otherwise your program will crash all the same. If Optional is available in your language, that's indeed a really good solution.

Comment: You can't validate ZipCode indepenently, so don't. You really need the Country object to look up the ZipCode/PostCode validation rules.

Comment: @Joshua I’d go further: you cannot validate a zip/post code _period_. The only way to validate a zip/post code is by having a lookup registry to every existing zip/post code in every country in the world.

Answer (score 11):

If you wrestle a lot with this question, perhaps the language you use is not the right tool for the job?
This kind of "domain-typed primitives" are trivially easy to express in, for example, F#.

There you could, for example, write:

```
type ZipCode = ZipCode of string
type Town = Town of string

type Adress = {
  zipCode: ZipCode
  town: Town
  //etc
}

let adress1 = {
  zipCode = ZipCode "90210"
  town = Town "Beverly Hills"
}

let faultyAdress = {
  zipCode = "12345"  // <-Compiler error
  town = adress1.zipCode // <- Compiler error
}
```

This is really useful for avoiding common mistakes, like comparing id's of different entities. And since these typed primitives are much more lightweight than a C# or Java-class, you'll end up actually use them.

Comment: Interesting - how would  it look like if you wanted to enforce validation of `ZipCode`?

Comment: @Hulk You can write OO-style in F# and make the types into classes. However, I prefer functional style, declaring the type with type ZipCode = private ZipCode of string and adding a ZipCode module with a create function.
There are some examples here: https://gist.github.com/swlaschin/54cfff886669ccab895a

Comment: @Bent-Tranberg Thanks for the edit. You are right, a simple type abbreviation does not give compile time type security.

Comment: If you was mailed my first comment, that I deleted, the reason was that I first misunderstood your source. I didn't read it carefully enough. When I tried to compile it, I finally realized that you were actually trying to demonstrate exactly this, so then I decided to edit to get it right.

Comment: Yeah. My original source was valid alright, unfortunately including the example that was SUPPOSED to be invalid. Doh! Should hav just linked to Wlaschin instead of typing code myself :)
https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/

Answer (score 6):

The answer depends entirely on what you actually want to do with the ZIP codes. Here are two extreme possibilities:

(1) All addresses are guaranteed to be in a single country. No exceptions at all. (E.g. no foreign customers, or no employees whose private address is abroad while they are working for a foreign customer.) This country has ZIP codes and they can be expected to never be seriously problematic (i.e. they don't require free-form input such as "currently D4B 6N2, but this changes every 2 weeks"). The ZIP codes are used not just for addressing, but for validation of payment information or similar purposes. - Under these circumstances, a ZIP code class makes a lot of sense.

(2) Addresses can be in almost every country, so dozens or hundreds of addressing schemes with or without ZIP codes (and with thousands of weird exceptions and special cases) are relevant. A "ZIP" code is really only asked for to remind people from countries where ZIP codes are used not to forget to provide theirs. The addresses are only used so that if someone loses access to their account and they can prove their name and address, access will be restored. - Under these circumstances, ZIP code classes for all relevant countries would be an enormous effort. Fortunately they are not needed at all.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have talked about OO domain modelling and using a richer type to represent your value.

I don't disagree, especially given the example code you posted.

But I also wonder if that actually answers the title of your question.

Consider the following scenario (pulled from an actual project I'm working on):

You have a remote application on a field device that talks to your central server. One of the DB fields for the device entry is a zip code for the address that the field device is at. You don't care about the zip code (or any of the rest of the address for that matter). All of the people who care about it are on the other side of an HTTP boundary: you just happen to be the single source of truth for the data. It has no place in your domain modeling. You just record it, validate it, store it, and on request shuffle it off in a JSON blob to points elsewhere.

In this scenario, doing much of anything beyond validating the insert with an SQL regex constraint (or its ORM equivalent) is *probably* overkill of the YAGNI variety.

Comment: Your SQL regex constraint could be viewed as a qualified type - within your database, the Zip code is not stored as "VarChar" but "VarChar constrained by this rule". In some DBMSes, you could easily give that type+constraint a name as a reusable "domain type", and we are back in the recommended place of giving the data a meaningful type. I agree with your answer in principle, but don't think that example matches; a better example would be if your data is "raw sensor data", and the most meaningful type is "byte array" because you have no idea what the data means.

Comment: @IMSoP interesting point. Not sure I agree though: you could validate a string zip code in Java (or any other language) with a regex but still be dealing with it as a string instead of a richer type. Depending on the domain logic, further manipulation might be required (for instance ensuring that the zip code matches the state, something that would be difficult/impossible to validate with regex).

Comment: You *could*, but as soon as you do so, you are ascribing it some domain-specific behaviour, and that is exactly what the quoted articles are saying should lead to the creation of a custom type. The question is not whether you *can* do it in one style or the other, but whether you *should*, assuming your programming language gives you the choice.

Comment: You could model such a thing as a `RegexValidatedString`, containing the string itself and the regex used to validate it. But unless every instance has a unique regex (which is possible but unlikely) this seems a bit silly and wasteful of memory (and possibly regex compilation time). So you either put the regex into a separate table and leave behind a lookup key in each instance to find it (which is arguably worse due to indirection) or you find some way to store it once for each common type of value sharing that rule -- eg. a static field on a domain type, or equivalent method, as IMSoP said.

Answer (score 2):

The `ZipCode` abstraction could only make sense if your `Address` class did not also have a `TownName` property. Otherwise, you have half an abstraction: the zip code designates the town, but these two related bits of information are found in different classes. It doesn't quite make sense.

However, even then, it's still not a correct application (or rather solution to) primitive obsession; which, as I understand it, mainly focuses on two things:

1. Using primitives as the input (or even output) values of a method, especially when a collection of primitives is needed.
2. Classes that grow extra properties over time without ever reconsidering whether some of these should be grouped into a subclass of their own.

Your case is neither. An address is a well-defined concept with clearly necessary properties (street, number, zip, town, state, country, ...). There is little to no reason to break up this data as it has a **single** responsibility: designate a location on Earth. An address requires **all** of these fields in order to be meaningful. Half an address is pointless.

This is how you know that you don't need to subdivide any further: breaking it down any further would detract from the functional intention of the `Address` class. Similarly, you don't need a `Name` subclass to be used in the `Person`class, unless `Name` (without a person attached) is a meaningful concept in your domain. Which it (usually) isn't. Names are used for identifying people, they usually have no value on their own.

Comment: I disagree. In some cases it makes perfect sense to add a Name type to a Person class, *if* there are additional business rules attached to a Name. You wouldn't want to handle the rules for names in the Person class. Same for validating ZipCodes, it makes perfect sense to make a ZipCode type inside an Address class.

Comment: @RikD: From the answer: _"you don't need a `Name` subclass to be used in the `Person` class, **unless Name** (without a person attached) **is a meaningful concept in your domain**."_ When you have custom validation for the names, the name has then become a meaningful concept in your domain; which I explicitly mentioned as a valid use case for using a subtype. Secondly, for the zipcode validation, you're introducing additional assumptions, such as zip codes needing to follow a given country's format. You're broaching a topic that's much broader than the intent of OP's question.

Comment: I disagreed with part of your post, not everything. We're on the same page when it comes to the Person class. You seem to argue that ZipCode is not a good abstraction in an Address class; I disagree with that. I'm not making assumptions; OP clearly states he wants to validate a ZipCode, noone (but you) is talking about other countries. In my opinion, the validation of that ZipCode belongs in the ZipCode class; *if* you want to validate it against a Town, the validate method in de ZipCode class should have an argument for TownName (OP didn't mention this either).

Comment: @RikD: Zip code assumes United States Postal Service, and you can derive the name of the town from the zip code. Cities can have multiple zip codes, but each zip code is only tied to 1 city. It actually makes sense to get the city and state from the zip code (in the USA at least).

Comment: "_An address is a well-defined concept with clearly necessary properties (street, number, zip, town, state, country)._" - [Well that's just plain wrong.](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/) For a good way to deal with this, look at Amazon's address form.

Comment: @R.Schmitz The format of an address is different from the properties it has. Yes, culturally it can be formatted different ways, but the property declaration is not responsible for making that decision. It only defines which fields are possible. My answere did not address address validation, which your linked page is mostly about (that and formats, also not my focus). Additionally, not every culture has these wildly varying address formats (Belgium and the Netherlands have a rather fixed format for all listed cases). Additionally, not every application is built to be used internationally.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Thanks for the info. I don't think you can assume that because someone uses the term ZipCode, they are from the USA. Personally I also use that term to define local postal codes. But even so, to validate if a ZipCode belongs to the town or city entered by the user, I think the best place to put this responsibility is inside the ZipCode class, don't you agree?

Comment: @R.Schmitz: I will, however, correct my answer to clarifythat the list of fields I mentioned is not a complete list.

Comment: @Flater Well I won't blame you for not reading the full list of falsehoods, because it's quite long, but it literally contains "Addresses will have a street", "An address require both a city and a country", "An address will have a postcode" etc., which is contrary to what the quoted sentence says.

Comment: @R.Schmitz: No it's not. I did not discuss input validation, I discussed _fields needed in the address class_. Just because _some_ addresses may not use a street/country/box/... field does not mean that the street/country/box/...property can be removed from the address class altogether. Of course some properties may be empty for some addresses, but that is not the point I was making (nor the opposite thereof).

Comment: @RikD: yeah, the ZipCode class is the best place to validate the format of the zip code,but I think other people brought up good points in the comments about validations beyond the format, for instance that 00501 is not just a valid format, but is indeed a recognized postal code with the USPS (Holtsville, New York). If you need to interact with an outside resource, it's going to be a judgement call.

Comment: @GregBurghardt "Zip code assumes United States Postal Service, and you can derive the name of the town from the zip code. Cities can have multiple zip codes, but each zip code is only tied to 1 city."  This is not correct in general.  I have a zipcode that is used mainly for a neighboring city but my residence is not located there.  Zipcodes do not always align with governmental boundaries.  For example 42223 contains [counties from both TN and KY](https://www.zip-codes.com/zip-code/42223/zip-code-42223.asp).

Comment: @GregBurghardt More information here: [USPS ZIP Codes are not areal features but a collection of mail delivery routes.](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/zctas.html)  And here ["The best example of this “placeless” designation is the US Navy, which has its own ZIP code, but no permanent location."](https://www.policymap.com/2013/04/tips-on-zips-part-iii-making-sense-of-zip-code-boundaries/)

Comment: @JimmyJames: Yeah. Addresses. They give me a migraine every time I think of them. Nothing about addresses is *ever* easy.

Comment: @JimmyJames I too have a zip code that crosses city boundaries, and it occasionally causes issues for me mainly because the DMV apparently designed their systems with the assumption that zip code = city so my drivers license lists the wrong city. You would also think the think that the people working for my city would see it often enough it wouldn't be a problem but... "You live in X, you should go there for: pool, dump, library, voting, etc."

Comment: My favorite counter-example for beliefs about addresses is the Grand Canyon North Rim Lodge.  The full address is `Grand Canyon Lodge, North Rim, Arizona 86052`.  No house number, no street name, no town ("North Rim" is the name of the post office).  The only element that every mailing address in the United States has is a zip code, although there's almost always something you can shoehorn into the "town" and "state" slots.

Comment: In Austria there exists a valley which is only accessible from Germany (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleinwalsertal). There exists a special treaty for this region which, among other things, also includes that adresses in this area have both Austrian and German postal codes. So in general, you cannot even assume that an address has only a single valid postal code ;)

Answer (score 1):

From the article:

> More generally, the yo-yo problem can also refer to any situation where a person must keep flipping between different sources of information in order to understand a concept.

Source code is *read* far more often than it is written. Thus, the yo-yo problem, of having to switch between many files is a concern.

However, *no*, the yo-yo problem feels much more relevant when dealing with deeply interdependent modules or classes (which call back and forth between each other). Those are a special kind of nightmare to read, and is likely what the coiner of the yo-yo problem had in mind.

However - *yes*, avoiding too many layers of abstraction is important!

> All non-trivial abstractions, to some degree, are leaky. - the Law of Leaky Abstractions.

For example, I disagree with the assumption made in [mmmaaa's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/386042/5038) that "you *don't* need to yo-yo to [(visit)] the ZipCode class to understand the Address class". My experience has been that you *do* - at least the first few times you read the code. However, as others have noted, there *are* times when a `ZipCode` class is appropriate.

YAGNI (Ya Ain't Gonna Need It) is a better pattern to follow to avoid Lasagna code (code with too many layers) - abstractions, such as types and classes are there to aid the programmer, and should not be used unless they *are* an aid.

I personally aim to "save lines of code" (and of course the related "save files/modules/classes", etc). I'm confident there are some who would apply to me the epithet of "primitive obsessed" - I find it more important to have code which is *easy to reason about* than to worry about labels, patterns, and anti-patterns. The correct choice of when to create a function, a module/file/class, or put a function in a common location is very situational. I aim roughly for 3-100 line functions, 80-500 line files, and "1, 2, n" for reusable library code ([SLOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code) - not including comments or boilerplate; I typically want at least 1 additional SLOC minimum per line of mandatory boilerplate). The important point is to keep in mind and respect the limits of human cognition when writing code.

Most positive patterns have arisen from developers doing exactly that, *when they needed them*. It is much more important to learn how to write readable code than to try to apply patterns without the same problem to solve. Any good developer can implement the factory pattern without having seen it before in the uncommon case where it is the right fit for their problem. I have used the factory pattern, the observer pattern, and probably hundreds besides, without knowing their name (ie, is there a "variable assignment pattern"?). For a fun experiment - see how many GoF patterns are built into the JS *language* - I stopped counting after about 12-15 back in 2009. The Factory pattern is as simple as returning an object from a JS constructor, for example - no need for a WidgetFactory.

So - *yes*, *sometimes* `ZipCode` is a good class. However, *no*, the yo-yo problem is not strictly relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The yo-yo problem is only relevant if you have to flip back and forth.  That is caused by one or two things (sometimes both):

1. Bad naming.  ZipCode seem fine, ZoneImprovementPlanCode is going to require a look by most people (and the few that don’t won’t be impressed).
2. Inappropriate coupling.  Say you ZipCode class has an area code lookup.  You might think it makes sense because it’s handy, but it’s not really related to the ZipCode, and shoeing it into it means that now people don’t know where to go for things.

If you can look at the name and have a reasonable idea of what it does, and the methods and properties do reasonably obvious things, you don’t need to go look at the code, you can just use it.  That is the whole point of classes in the first place—-they are modular pieces of code that can be used and developed in isolation.  If you have to look at anything other than the API for the class to see what it does, it is at best a partial failure.

Answer (score -1):

Remember, there is no silver bullet. If you are writing an extremely simple app which needs to be crawled through fast, then a simple string may do the job. **However** in 98% of the times, a [Value Object](https://deviq.com/value-object/) as described by Eric Evans in DDD, would be the perfect fit. You can easily see all the benefits Value objects provide by reading around.